# How to add a new treeview at the selected node?

Tags: vb.net

I have a treeview with four levels; parent, child, grandchild, great-grandchild. My selectednode is at the grandchild level.

What I'm trying to do is to create a new "Treeview" at the grandchild - NO, I dont wnat to create a new node to the "selectednode" (grandchild). So it should be somelike this:

parent
    child
       grandchild             (New TreeView) PARENT which was grandchild
           great-grandchild                      child
           great-grandchild                      child
       grandchild                                             grandchild

It would be similar to a parent table where the mother and father went off and had new childern with a different spouse other than the spouse of there existing children.

```
   Private Sub PopulateRootLevel()
            ' query to find first round of parent
            PopulateNodes(dt, JCATreeView.Nodes)
    End Sub

Private Sub PopulateNodes(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal nodes As TreeNodeCollection)
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim tn As New TreeNode()
            tn.Text = dr("TITLE").ToString()
            tn.Value = dr("Parent_ID").ToString()
            nodes.Add(tn)

            'If node has child nodes, then enable on-demand populating
            tn.PopulateOnDemand = (CInt(dr("childnodecount")) > 0)
        Next
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateSubLevel(ByVal parentid As Integer, ByVal parentNode As TreeNode)

        ' query to find children of parent with child node count of parent
         da.Fill(dt)
        PopulateNodes(dt, parentNode.ChildNodes)
End Sub

Protected Sub TreeView1_TreeNodePopulate(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNodeEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.TreeNodePopulate
        ' add a test to determine if this is from TreeView1 or Sub_TreeView1
         PopulateSubLevel(CInt(e.Node.Value), e.Node)
End Sub

Protected Sub TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TreeView1.SelectedNodeChanged

        Dim selected_parent_id As Integer = sender.SelectedNode.value
        Parent_to_NEW_TREEVIEW_PopulateSubLevel(selected_parent_id, sender.SelectedNode)
End Sub

Private Sub Sub_TreeView1_PopulateSubLevel(ByVal parent_id As Integer, ByVal parentNode As TreeNode)

        ' Query to get new children of parents
        da.Fill(dt2)
        Sub_TreeView1_PopulateNodes(dt2, parentNode.ChildNodes)
End Sub

    Private Sub Sub_TreeView1_PopulateNodes(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal nodes As TreeNodeCollection)
        For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
            Dim tn As TreeNode = New TreeNode()
            'tn = parentBCNode.Nodes.Add("NEW_PARENT_TREEVIEW")

            ' query to get child on the new parent treeview

            tn.Text = dr("New parent title").ToString()
            tn.Value = dr("New_parent_ID").ToString()
            nodes.Add(tn)

            'If node has child nodes, then enable on-demand populating
            tn.PopulateOnDemand = (CInt(dr("childnodecount")) > 0)
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: A new "treeview" is just another node.  The real question is WHERE should the new node be added?  Is it a sibling to the selected node?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.
A TreeView can not have as one of its child nodes another TreeView control. The only thing you can do is assign the TreeView to the tag property of a TreeNode, but that will not be displayed (obviously).
 I don't understand why you would want to do that, unless you want a different drawing behavior for that grand-child sub-tree.
 You can make use of the treeNode.Level property to find out at which level that node is. And again you can create a custom object(that has all your required information) and store it in the treeNode.Tag property.